# Use Volley synchronous

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need to use volley sync (need to get server response then continues program)

I search a lot in stackOverFlow but i have problem with them
 this is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    //For ByPass Test
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Initials();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}

private void Initials(){
    String url = AppController.getInstance().getMainUrl() + "GetVer";
    String response = new String();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(), future, future);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    try {
        response = future.get().toString();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but when i debug program my app Block on this line

```
response = future.get().toString();
```

and i add timeout to this line but it will go to `TimeoutException`

```
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

after define time

i trace volley request on Logcat and request done with out any error

this is volley logcat

```
02-04 22:08:12.171 28508-28553/? D/Volley: [2249] bjk.b: new request, sending to network 1-https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download
02-04 22:08:12.381 17530-17637/ir.onecloud.elearning V/Volley: [2674] CacheDispatcher.run: start new dispatcher
02-04 22:08:12.586 17530-17637/ir.onecloud.elearning D/Volley: [2674] WaitingRequestManager.maybeAddToWaitingRequests: new request, sending to network http://shokribozorg.ir/WebService/WebService.asmx/GetVer
02-04 22:08:12.776 17530-17638/ir.onecloud.elearning D/Volley: [2675] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://shokribozorg.ir/WebService/WebService.asmx/GetVer 0x81eb498 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=176], [size=1], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
02-04 22:08:12.881 28508-28558/? D/Volley: [2255] bkm.a: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 0xc9395b26 NORMAL 7> [lifetime=709], [size=263], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (716  ms) [ ] https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/clientreport/download 0xc9395b26 NORMAL 7
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+0   ) [2244] add-to-queue
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+0   ) [2249] cache-queue-take
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+1   ) [2249] cache-miss
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+1   ) [2255] network-queue-take
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+709 ) [2255] network-http-complete
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+4   ) [2255] network-parse-complete
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+0   ) [2255] post-response
02-04 22:08:12.886 28508-28508/? D/Volley: [1] bkh.a: (+1   ) [ 1] done
02-04 22:08:16.631 18005-18039/? V/Volley: [2785] CacheDispatcher.run: start new dispatcher
```